# I can't install the elementary-transparent-theme

Tags: themes

I installed elementary-tweaks and wanted to install the transparent theme using this commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary` , `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get install elementary-transparent-theme` and i get this error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package elementary-transparent-theme
```

I use Loki 0.4.

Comment: Can you check /etc/apt/sources.list to confirm that the yunnxx/elementary repository has been added?

Answer (score 3):

You can't install/use the themes from this PPA because they are TOO OLD. (Just look at the upload dates!) They support only the older GTK+ versions of older elementary OS versions. elementary OS Loki runs with GTK+ 3.18, so you can only use themes supporting THIS EXACT GTK Version. Not GTK+ 3.14 (Freya) or earlier, not 3.20 or later (actual Ubuntu/Gnome versions).

It is NOT recommended installing a newer GTK version on elementary OS as it WILL break some looks and functionality on your system.

There are OSX-Arc themes on gnome-look.org that DO support GTK+ 3.18 but they break correct Wingpanel behaviour and will introduce a bug into Pantheon Photos (non refreshing background). 
AFAIK **[OSeArcLight](http://fav.me/dbh88n2)** is the only 3rd party theme at the moment that properly supports elementary OS Wingpanel, panel GTK widgets and Photos. Please note that it is still a bit buggy with GTK dialog windows and Granite apps. Otherwise usable. ... I know because I made it. =)

Also better not use a PPA just to install a theme. You can simply unpack themes into a hidden ~/.themes folder (or create it in your Home folder first).

Comment: If you really want a transparent theme and feel lucky, you can try this,too: 
 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lRaFHoTHleNVZsRmkyamw1VWs It's an Arc-remix I'm currently working on. Keep in mind that it's really early days for the theme, Files for example looks quite good, other things are messed up.  But if you can live with that and report me some bugs back, it would be win-win.

@wefunkster: looks like we had similar ideas (just tweaking themes a bit and ending up chanhing a lot)!

Comment: Yup, but by forking and repairing OSX-Arc I ran into some dead ends and Granite apps and some GTK dialogs still look sh*t. I'll soon start a new approach and directly use the stock elementary theme as a base. It IS extremely clean and well made but just a bit too dull grey and "heavy" to me. I also REALLY like the small color accent that Mac-like window buttons give.

Comment: PS: Just checked your theme: You also need to repair Wingpanel .panel css and basically everything regarding .popover and GTK widgets. I put a lot of time into this. Yet still I'll start new and fork the elementary theme instead.

Comment: So you'll say not worth the effort?  PS: wingpanel is looking okay here, what's the problem for you?  PPS: will you make it more like Arc, just with another cleaner base or will it be closer to default?

Comment: There is too much elementary specific code that is missing in other themes. It is very hard/difficult to coppy over the respective code and find out what of the old code to keep and what to ditch. Wingpanel is different than Gnome panel/shell Wingpanel is not using semitransparent background when it should, just fully transparent at all times (but for maximized windows it goes solid black, which it should).
No, not worth it. I'll start clean and just adjust, colors, some borders an window buttons.